# Импорт данных и производительность

Tags: php, mysql, php7

Появилась такая задачка: импорт в БД данных из CSV-файла. CSV представляет собой ненормализованную табличку, он прилетает из другого приложения и на его формат я повлиять никак не могу. БД нормальзована, поэтому вариант с LOAD DATA INFILE, наверное, не подойдет.

Условно, БД выглядит так:

```
CREATE TABLE `clients` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
`email` VARCHAR(30) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`), 
UNIQUE `index_clients_names` (`name`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `products` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
`price` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`), 
UNIQUE `index_products_names` (`name`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `orders` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`client` INT NOT NULL,
`product` INT NOT NULL,
`date_time` DATETIME NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`), 
UNIQUE `index_order_datetime` (`date_time`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

CSV-файл:

```
John Ridger;Paper;30;2018/10/7 5:23:54 AM
Василий Кормушкин;Notebook;8;2018/10/7 8:44:28 AM
Alice McCollin;Glue;5;2018/10/7 11:9:14 AM
...
```

Сначала мне нужно добавить недостающие поля (если таковых ранее не было в БД) в таблички clients и products, потом уже вносить данные в orders.

Соответственно, возник вопрос - как это сделать оптимально (и с т.з. производительности/нагрузки на СУБД, и с т.з. удобства кода (используется РНР7)).

В голову приходят такие варианты:

1. На РНР распарсить CSV в массив, затем пройтись по нему построчно с кучей  INSERT'ов (вида INSERT IGNORE INTO) с клиентами и продуктами (либо с несколькими многострочными INSERT'ами). Затем еще раз пройти по массиву, SELECT'ами получить id клиентов/товаров и делать INSERT в orders.
   *(Мне кажется, вариант дурацкий).*
2. Сделать в MySQL хранимую процедуру, принимающую имя клиента, названием товара, кол-во и дату, которая будет проверять наличие нужных значений в clients/products (и получать их id), при необходимости добавлять их туда, и в конце заносить данные в orders.
   *(Вроде бы вариант получше, не знаю только, нет ли в MySQL каких-то ограничений, которые могут не дать это сделать. Минус в том, что вызов процедуры придется делать для каждой строчки в CSV).*
3. Сделать VIEW из этих 3х табличек через INNER JOIN, повесить на него триггер BEFORE INSERT и в нем выполнить необходимую подготовку данных - получение id, добавление недостающих данных в clients/products. Соответственно, из РНР просто делать INSERT в этот VIEW. Может быть даже LOAD DATA INFILE.
   (*Если я правильно понял документацию по MySQL, то это невозможно из-за ограничений триггеров на кол-во изменяемых таблиц.*)
4. Сделать хранимую процедуру, которая будет создавать временную табличку, читать в нее CSV через LOAD DATA INFILE и затем уже производить манипуляции с этой таблицей, в конце смержить ее с orders.
   (*Вообще не уверен, что MySQL позволит такое. Если все же такое возможно, то не знаю, как скажется на производительности/потреблении ресурсов создание/удаление временной таблицы при каждом импорте данных*)

Больше ничего в голову не приходит, посему хотелось бы узнать мнение более опытных в этом деле людей.

Comment: Оптимальным будет вариант 1. Подключить кеширование. Написать функции getClientByName, getProductByName, в которых проверить - если запись есть в кеше, взять id из него, если нет в кеше - сделать селект в бд, если и там нет - создать новую запись в бд и скопировать в кеш. Таким образом радикально уменьшится кол-во селектов к бд. Ну и в цикле пройтись по вашему csv

Comment: И если эти самые таблички clients и products не очень большие (я что то сомневаюсь, что там миллионы строк), можно пойти еще проще, сразу целиком подгрузить их ассоциативные массивы с ключом в виде имени (которое приходит из csv). так что при добавлении новой записи вам достаточно будет взять id в виде `$clients[$name]`, если его там нет, добавить в БД и в этот массив. Если при всем этом вы включите транзации и будете давать commit скажем раз в 1000 записей. А так же один раз сделаете `prepare('insert ....')` и в цикле обработки будете давать только execute, то будет достаточно быстро

Comment: Спасибо, попробую так сделать.